# Is it possible to have NSwag ignore a controller?

Tags: c#, swagger, nswag

I used NSwag to generate a client for a single controller; I needed it as its own separate client.  I would like for it to be ignored when the Swagger specification is generated in the future.

I tried adding this attribute at the top of the controller but it is still being noted in the specification:
`[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]`

My controller is implementing the standard `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller` class.

Comment: Attributes are not the only way to do it, here's an alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77267347/1667351

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think in the latest version,

```
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
```

is supported.

Otherwise you can add the `SwaggerIgnoreAttribute` OR `OpenApiIgnoreAttribute` attribute

```
[SwaggerIgnore]
[OpenApiIgnore]
```

Or manually select the controllers in NSwagStudio or in the middleware...

Comment: I have the latest version but that annotation still didn't work for me.  Using `[NSwag.Annotations.SwaggerIgnore]` ended up being the best solution.

Comment: Strange: https://github.com/NSwag/NSwag/blob/master/src/NSwag.SwaggerGeneration.WebApi.Tests/Attributes/ApiExplorerSettingsAttributeTests.cs

Comment: That test only demonstrates that attribute works when placed over a method.  I was interested in knocking out the entire controller with one attribute.  `[SwaggerIgnore]` does just that, thankfully.

Comment: I see, next version will also support this scenario: https://github.com/NSwag/NSwag/commit/bbebc00af5f4c490049db9e77f440c7693069f38

Comment: `[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]` is needed if you also have `using System.Web.Http.Description;` in your Controller

Answer (score 17):

Use
 `[OpenApiIgnore]`

(since `[SwaggerIgnore]` has been deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

@Arieh 's answer worked for me.
I'd like to share more.

1. Install package `NSwag.Annotations` for DTO class, for my case which is in separated project, then use `[OpenApiIgnore]` decorate the property which should be ignored.
2. Install package `NSwag.AspNetCore` for the web project.

Comment: is this work for any one ?