# NSwag : How can i suppress controllers ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nswag

ASP.NEt Core 3.1
I would like to suppress one certain controller. Therefore i tried use the DocumentProcessor, but without success.

```
public class DocumentProcessor : IDocumentProcessor
```

I have **no** access to this specific controller. So i need a solution like ist was possible before.
It was possible in ASP.NET MVC by "filtering" the controllers.

old code:

```
var controllers = new[] { typeof(ExternalApiController)
                                        , typeof(ExternalApiDatasourceController)                                        
                                    };

var document = Task.Run(async () => await generator.GenerateForControllersAsync(controllers)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option is to implement and register a custom operation process and exclude all operations of this controller (return false): https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/wiki/Document-Processors-and-Operation-Processors#operation-processors

Answer (score 0):

To make Rico's answer concrete, here's how to do it in your scenario. Let's say you want to exclude your `ExternalApiController` and related schema from showing up in Swagger. You would first create a custom document post-processor for NSwag, like this:

```
using NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore;
using NSwag.Generation.Processors;
using NSwag.Generation.Processors.Contexts;

public class NswagPostProcessor : IOperationProcessor
{
    public bool Process(OperationProcessorContext context)
    {
        var apiAction = ((AspNetCoreOperationProcessorContext)context).ApiDescription.ActionDescriptor;
        bool? isUnwantedController = apiAction?.DisplayName?.Contains("ExternalApiController");

        return !isUnwantedController.HasValue || isUnwantedController.Value == false;
    }
}
```

Then, in `Program.cs`, simply insert the custom processor into the processor pipeline to apply it:

```
builder.Services.AddOpenApiDocument(config =>
{
    config.OperationProcessors.Insert(0, new NswagPostProcessor());
});
```

The result of the `Process` operation determines whether the endpoint shows up in Swagger, so you can control it that way.